# Is there a way to search in sqlite date by more than Entry of tkinter (ignoring the blank entry)?

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I created a tkinter connected to sqlite file, with Entries for search of workers data, for example: name, qualification, job.
I need to search with more than Entry in the same time so I write for example:

```
c.execute("SELECT *,oid FROM data WHERE name LIKE ? and qualification LIKE ? and job LIKE ?", ('%' + self.name.get() + '%', '%' + self.qualification.get() + '%', '%' + self.job.get() + '%'))
```

the problem encountered me when I search by one Entry or two and leave the third Entry blank, and because the data of column for that Entry is not blank, that leads to 0 results, I thought to use "If" but that will lead to complicated code with more Entries, is there any way to solve that?
thanks for help

Comment: Use an `if` that is the easiest way, IMO. `if not self.job.get(): return`.

Comment: When i use 9 or 10 entries for search, with 'if' the code will be very long, that's my problem

Comment: Give more code related to the entry widget, where is the entry widget. Are you going to use ALL the entry widgets inside root? How many entry widgets will there be maximum. You should provide all the required information.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm using 11 entry for search, add, and edit (number, name, job, qualification, state, job grade, branch, administration, date of birth, date of employing), i displayed my problem briefly, i'm sorry for that

Comment: Edit in your code to show the creation of these entries and some more details then.